# How to use the result of the previous row and sub it with the minimum of the result and given value

Tags: r

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1LVHg.png)

Please find image of the table. column E and F are my resultant columns. I am new to R so need some help here. I am able to do it in excel not able to do it in R.

formula for column E: `=IF(A2=A1,MIN(C2,F1),MIN(D2,C2))`

formula for column F: `=IF(A2=A1,F1-E2,D2-E2)`

After 1st row of calculation which is simple. From next row It takes the result of previous row within a group(lag(remaining)-excess at batch level) and for column E it takes min(totalvalue,lag(remaining)) and continue this till it reaches the end of that group.

please guide me how to approach this in r

example data

```
       group totalQty totalValue Excess_at_national_level Excess.at.batch.level Remaining
1 3MCAVSB01A        1        987                     4935                   987      3948
2 3MCAVSB01A        1        987                     4935                   987      2961
3 3MCAVSB01A        1        987                     4935                   987      1974
4 3MCAVSB01A        1        987                     4935                   987       987
5 3MCAVSB01A        2       1974                     4935                   987         0
6 3MCAVSB01A        1        987                     4935                     0         0
7 3MCAVSB01A        1        987                     4935                     0         0

my_data <- data.frame(
          stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
                     group = c("3MCAVSB01A",
                               "3MCAVSB01A","3MCAVSB01A","3MCAVSB01A",
                               "3MCAVSB01A","3MCAVSB01A","3MCAVSB01A"),
                  totalQty = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L),
                totalValue = c(987L, 987L, 987L, 987L, 1974L, 987L, 987L),
  Excess_at_national_level = c(4935L, 4935L, 4935L, 4935L, 4935L, 4935L, 4935L),
     Excess.at.batch.level = c(987L, 987L, 987L, 987L, 987L, 0L, 0L),
                 Remaining = c(3948L, 2961L, 1974L, 987L, 0L, 0L, 0L)
)
```

Comment: We cannot copy data from an image. Add them in a reproducible format which is easier to copy. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: @RonakShah I have provided a link to google sheet to copy the data. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it is possible to create a loop that fills in the cells iteratively using very similar formulas, I think this would be a more idiomatic R approach, and would be much faster than a loop if you were working with larger data than Excel is built for.

```
library(dplyr)
my_data %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(cuml_totalValue = cumsum(totalValue),
         Remaining_new = pmax(0, Excess_at_national_level - cuml_totalValue),
         Excess.at.batch.level_new = if_else(row_number() == 1, totalValue + 0,
                                             pmin(totalValue, lag(Remaining_new, default = 0)))) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Output (not that the last two new columns match the desired output)

```
  group    totalQty totalValue Excess_at_national_l… Excess.at.batch.le… Remaining cuml_totalValue Remaining_new Excess.at.batch.leve…
  <chr>       <int>      <int>                 <int>               <int>     <int>           <int>         <dbl>                 <dbl>
1 3MCAVSB…        1        987                  4935                 987      3948             987          3948                   987
2 3MCAVSB…        1        987                  4935                 987      2961            1974          2961                   987
3 3MCAVSB…        1        987                  4935                 987      1974            2961          1974                   987
4 3MCAVSB…        1        987                  4935                 987       987            3948           987                   987
5 3MCAVSB…        2       1974                  4935                 987         0            5922             0                   987
6 3MCAVSB…        1        987                  4935                   0         0            6909             0                     0
7 3MCAVSB…        1        987                  4935                   0         0            7896             0                     0
```